# Flask : How to pass JSON to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have object main.py

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify,send_file,render_template
import json
# from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/vendor')
# CORS(app)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html',id_user="id1")


@app.route('/receive_word',methods=['POST'])
def receive_word():
    print(request.form)
    data = request.form['javascript_data']
    d = json.loads(data)
    print(d['key1'])
    print(d['key2'])
    return d
```

I have microphone.js

```
$.post("/receive_word", {
    javascript_data: JSON.stringify({ "key1":1, "key2":this.currentTranscript })
});
console.log({{ d }});
```

How can I pass d in my main.py to main.js? The code can't caught the d variable from main.py
Thank you

Comment: Is `microphone.js` the same as `main.js`, if not where is `main.js`?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use JQuery to make your call to your endpoint. You should use the `$.post` callback parameter :

```js
$.post("/receive_word", {
    javascript_data: JSON.stringify({ "key1":1, "key2":this.currentTranscript })
}, 
// Here is the callback
function(d, status){
     // process d
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jsonify` to return json data in Flask view, assume that `d` is a valid Python dict:

```
@app.route('/receive_word',methods=['POST'])
def receive_word():
    data = request.form['javascript_data']
    d = json.loads(data)   
    return jsonify(d)
```